# Kubernetes rolling deploy: terminate a pod only when there are no containers running

Tags: kubernetes, containers, google-kubernetes-engine, continuous-deployment, kubernetes-pod

I am trying to deploy updates to pods. However I want the current pods to terminate only when all the containers inside the pod have terminated and their process is complete.

The new pods can keep waiting to start untill all container in the old pods have completed. We have a mechanism to stop old pods from picking up new tasks and therefore they should eventually terminate.

It's okay if twice the pods exist at some instance of time. I tried finding solution for this in kubernetes docs but wan't successful. Pointers on how / if this is possible would be helpful.

Comment: One of the first steps of the termination process is that the container process will receive SIGTERM; can you capture this and start your clean shutdown process?  How long does it take to finish the tasks?

Comment: Tasks can take 10+ hours to complete, but they are user facing tasks so can't abruptly end them. Handling SIGTERM is a good idea, tho handler can't be waiting for all process to complete as some kernel process continues forever, we may need to poll active processes by their name and wait.

Answer (score 0):

well I guess then you may have to create a duplicate kind of deployment with new image as required and change the selector in service to new deployment, which will prevent external traffic from entering pre-existing pods and new calls can go to new pods. Then later you can check for something like -

```
Kubectl top pods -c containers
```

and if the load appears to be static and low, then preferrably you can delete the old pods related deployment later.

But for this thing everytime the service selectors have to be updated and likely for keeping track of things you can append the git commit hash to the service selector to keep it unique everytime.

But rollback to previous versions if required from inside Kubernetes cluster will be difficult, so preferably you can trigger the wanted build again.

I hope this makes some sense !!